# Content not displayed when using display block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
button {
  content: url('https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/009/663/667/original/pencil-icon-transparent-free-png.png');
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="common">
  <button class="flex" arial-label="delete" data-icon="delete"></button>
  <button class="block" arial-label="delete" data-icon="delete"></button>
</div>
```

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/sejunb/pen/rNZKWjd)

Why is the image not showing in the second button ? I expected for the content in the second button to also appear. I tried looking through the specification but could not find much information.

EDIT: It looks like the image appears in the second button only in Google Chrome.

Comment: none of the buttons displays an image

Comment: @Johannes The top one does for me

Comment: Make that in Chrome but not FF

Answer (score 2):

If you want an image as the element background, then use the [background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

```
button {
  background: center / cover no-repeat url('https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/009/663/667/original/pencil-icon-transparent-free-png.png'), white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Note that this is shorthand for multiple properties.  Take some time to understand each - they are very useful.